# Как отфильтровать SQL-запрос по столбцам в SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite, flask-sqlalchemy

Я новичок в Flask Alchemy. Я хочу отфильтровать запрос SQL о значениях столбца `LOC_CODE`. Я сделал `db.session.query(schools).filter_by(LOC_CODE='X270').first()`. Но компилятор возвращает:

```
(base) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\musicaltroupefinder>python hello_world.py
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py:835: FSADeprecationWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True or False to suppress this warning.
  'SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and '
 * Serving Flask app "hello_world" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
[2019-12-20 13:03:58,460] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1249, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 580, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: schools.LOC_CODE

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "hello_world.py", line 32, in index
    school = School.query.filter(School.LOC_CODE == 'X270').all()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 3186, in all
    return list(self)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 3342, in __iter__
    return self._execute_and_instances(context)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 3367, in _execute_and_instances
    result = conn.execute(querycontext.statement, self._params)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 988, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 287, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1107, in _execute_clauseelement
    distilled_params,
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1253, in _execute_context
    e, statement, parameters, cursor, context
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1473, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_from_cause(sqlalchemy_exception, exc_info)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 398, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 152, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1249, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 580, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such column: schools.LOC_CODE
[SQL: SELECT schools."LOC_CODE" AS "schools_LOC_CODE"
FROM schools
WHERE schools."LOC_CODE" = ?]
[parameters: ('X270',)]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Dec/2019 13:03:58] "[1m[35mGET / HTTP/1.1[0m" 500 -
```

Вот весь код:

```
from flask import Flask 
from flask import render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapper, sessionmaker

from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///mydb.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class School(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'schools'
    # __table_args__ = { 'extend_existing': True }
    LOC_CODE = db.Column(db.Text, primary_key=True)   


@app.route("/")
def index():
    school = School.query.filter(School.LOC_CODE == 'X270').first()
    print("School's name is", school.SCHOOLNAME)
    return render_template("index.html")
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте изменить название столбца в нижний регистр:

```
class School(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'schools'        
    loc_code = db.Column(db.Text, primary_key=True)
```